# Implement CI/CD using Bitbucket/Git and Codeship

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, ci, cicd

I'm trying to implement CI/CD using Bitbucket and Codeship(a CD tool like Jenkins) to achieve continuous deployment in Salesforce Orgs along with code versioning. I'm confused with the new folder structure which gets generated by VSCode(the config, app, manifest folders). The question I have is to understand where to put ANT build.xml, build.properties ant-salesforce.jar files.
I want to understand the folder structure for ANT related files.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar setup in Azure DevOps and here is how it looks like -

[image]

You can have your own folder structure but make sure to map ant-salesforce.jar & build.properties in your build.xml. Also, when you run your CI/CD point to folder containing build.xml.